# CodenameOne app build giving Retrolambda IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, codenameone, illegalargumentexception, retrolambda

Whenever I try uploading my CodenameOne app to the build server, it is responding with an error, see below:

```
00:00 ERROR: Failed to run Retrolambda
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:185)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:168)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.ClassAnalyzer.analyze(ClassAnalyzer.java:25)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda$1.visitClass(Retrolambda.java:62)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.files.ClasspathVisitor.visitFile(ClasspathVisitor.java:29)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.files.ClasspathVisitor.visitFile(ClasspathVisitor.java:11)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda.visitFiles(Retrolambda.java:98)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda.run(Retrolambda.java:59)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Main.main(Main.java:28)
00:00 ERROR: Failed to run Retrolambda
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:185)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:168)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.ClassAnalyzer.analyze(ClassAnalyzer.java:25)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda$1.visitClass(Retrolambda.java:62)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.files.ClasspathVisitor.visitFile(ClasspathVisitor.java:29)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.files.ClasspathVisitor.visitFile(ClasspathVisitor.java:11)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda.visitFiles(Retrolambda.java:98)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda.run(Retrolambda.java:59)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Process return code is 1
```

It works perfectly fine while testing using the simulator, and only returns an error on the build server. I assume this has to do with the fact that it's building for Android.

I'm using Java 11 (I have set this in my build options for codename one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target language level needs to be Java 8 not Java 11. You can use JDK 11 but the target setting needs to be 8.

Comment: I completely believe that this is the problem, but I've changed everything back to 8, but it's still not building, same error every time.

Comment: There might be some classes cached or remaining from previously. I suggest manually deleting all class and jar files in the project and trying to send a new build

Comment: It was an issue with one of my dependencies. Thank you!